# Finding individual vectors given a dot product or vector length

Tags: linear-algebra

$$u \cdot v = 2\\
v \cdot w = -6\\
u \cdot w = -3\\
||u|| = 1\\
||v|| = 2\\
||w|| = 7\\$$

(a) $<2v - w, 3u + 2w>$

If I'm given a vector length or dot product like the above how can I find the individual vectors so that I can calculate (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the individual vector to find (a). You are looking for $(2v-w)\cdot (3u+2w)$. Using distributive law gives you:

$$6v\cdot u+4v\cdot w-3w\cdot u-2w\cdot w$$

Note that $w\cdot w=||w||^2$.

I hope you can continue from there.